# How to get the colorID of a specific event in google calendar

Tags: php, google-api, google-calendar-api

Is there a way to access the colorID of a specific event in the google calendar? There are a lot of tutorials telling how to SET the colorID of an event but I am in need of a way to GET the colorID of an event already in the google calendar.

Comment: did you find solution ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Narayan: Yes, it's actually ver simple. Just test any events response from within google calendar's page (the api page where you can test the REST API) and make sure the event has a color too. You would then see that the colorid is there in the response. So basically, you will just set the colorid like any other normal property of the calendar.